# jquery textarea custom tags replacement

Tags: jquery, regex, textarea, replace

I'm basically trying to create my own tags - and replace them with the right HTML tags. So `{B} {/B}` would turn into `<b> </b>`

I have only got so far with this, here: http://www.nacremedia.com/text2.htm

Use the [B] button to bold stuff the current selection... it creates two bold tags and one closing for some reason.

I'm so close! But I just need a bit of direction to get the final bugs out - can anyone please help??

Also, if there is a better way of doing this altogether then I am more than welcome to new ideas.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create your own version of [BBCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode). Why?

Comment: Are there any bugs in particular you're worried about? Just the extra `<b>` being created?

Comment: It would probably be a help if you included the jQuery you're using. I know it'll be on the linked page, somewhere, but it's vastly more useful **in the question**.

Comment: In this line: $("textarea").surroundSelectedText('{B}'+ text,'{/B}');
Why is "text" being concatenated in the first parameter?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: yeah it's just that annoying extra <b>, really :\

  @Matt Ball - Sorry, but that's irrelevant to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a series of .replace() functions on strings. For instance:

```
var your_string = "{B}Testing{/B}";
your_string.replace("{B}", "<b>");
your_string.replace("{/B}", "</b>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to bold the text "Test" then, at the very end of the for loop in replaceArray replaceString's value is <b>dsaf<</i>b>

This happens because at the final step of the loop the forward slash in <b>Test</b> matches the regular expression /[/I]/g because brackets in regular expressions specify character classes.  Rather than looking for "[/I]" in the string the regular expression is actually looking for either a foward slash or the character I.

Finally, when being inserted into the output div the browser is autoclosing the first bold tag and omitting the closing italics tag, leaving what appears to be an extra bold tag at the end.

Escaping the brackets in "[/I]" should fix your problem, or, better yet, change it to "{/I}" to be both avoid the issue and also be consistent with how bold is implemented.

For more information on regex character classes please see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

One last thing, the functional chapter of eloquent javascript (http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html) explains very well one of the better ways of parsing and generating markup.